# Groovy static compilation fails when using generics and extended traits

Tags: java, generics, groovy, compiler-errors, traits

I get error when I compile the following code:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class Test {
  trait BaseTrait {}
  trait ExtendingTrait extends BaseTrait {}
  static class BaseTraitImplementor implements BaseTrait {}
  static class ExtendingTraitImplementor implements ExtendingTrait {}
  static class BothTraitImplementor implements ExtendingTrait, BaseTrait {}
  static class UsingTraits<T extends BaseTrait> {}
  UsingTraits<BaseTraitImplementor> instance1
  UsingTraits<ExtendingTraitImplementor> instance2 // <- compiler complains here
  UsingTraits<BothTraitImplementor> instance3
}
```

Compilation error:

```
Groovy-Eclipse: Bound mismatch: The type Test.ExtendingTraitImplementor is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Test.BaseTrait> of the type Test.UsingTraits<T>
```

It looks like compiler does not resolve that ExtendingTrait actually extends BaseTrait and I need to provide it manually (see BothTraitImplementor class).

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I found out an answer. It turns out that Groovy-Eclipse compiler is outdated and has a lot of bugs. When I switched to groovyc everything went smoothly.